# How is Cursor To Selected calculated in this scenario?

Tags: faces, 3d-cursor

I have four (4) objects and when I select all of them and press <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode*, I can select the top face of each object. Then when I do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor To Selected* I would have expected the *3D Cursor* to be averaged at the center but alas it didn't. Can anyone explain how the *Cursor To Selected* is calculated in this scenario?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3D cursor usually goes to the *Median Point*, since this is the default setting for the *Transform Pivot Point*.

What you need to snap it to is the center of the overall shape which would be the *Bounding Box Center* as pivot point. Simply change it in the top menu.

Note: for the *Cursor to Selected* snapping you can only use the *Bounding Box Center* and *Median Point* options. All other pivot points set the cursor to the default *Median Point*. And it's only working in *Edit Mode*, not *Object Mode*.

[image: snapping pivot]

Comment: oh yeah i totally forgot we got those options. thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie But it only works exclusively in _Edit Mode_ - if you wanted to do that in _Object Mode_ to get the bounding box center of all objects combined, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it goes to the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) point of the coordinates of selected vertices.